# Tippecanoe, Shapefile to MBTiles

Tags: qgis, mbtiles, xyz-tiles, tippecanoe

Is this normal when converting GeoJSON or shape files to MBTiles? Where it seen like the MBTiles will always have this offset when viewed up close. I think it viewed at zoom 23.

https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/968

[image: Source overlap MBTiles]

Comment: Raster or vector tiles?

Comment: Convert to vector MBTiles